# Proof Verification Of Theorem On Simple Function.

Tags: measure-theory

> **Theorem:**
> $(X,\mathcal A,\mu)$ be measure space.And $f$ and $g$ are two non negative simple function on $X$ such that$$ \int_X f ~~d\mu=\int_X g ~~d\mu <\infty ,~~~~ \int_E f ~~d\mu=\int_E g~~ d\mu$$
>
> For every $E\in \mathcal A$.then $f=g ~~\mu$ almost everywhere.

**Proof:**

Let $K=\left \{t\in X : f(t)\neq g(t)\right\}$ , $f=\sum_\limits{i=1}^na_i ~ \mathcal X_{E_i}~~$, $g=\sum_\limits{j=1}^mb_j ~ \mathcal X_{F_j}$  are canonical representation.

If $K=\phi$ Then we are done. else let $t\in K$ .Then $t\in E_{i_1}$ and $t\in F_{j_1}$ for some $i_1$ and $j_1$.but then it implies $ E_{i_1}\cap  F_{j_1}\subset K$.Now if $ E_{i_1}\cap  F_{j_1}\neq K$ then choose $ t_1\in K\setminus  E_{i_1}\cap  F_{j_1}$, and proceeding in similar way and fact that we have finitely many $E_i$"s.after some steps we have
$$ \bigcup_{t=1}^m \left( E_{i_t}\cap  F_{j_t}\right)=K$$.

So $K\in \mathcal A$ let $M_c= E_{i_c}\cap  F_{j_c}$ and now we show $\mu (M_c)=0$ for each c.$$ a_{i_c}\cdot \mu ( E_{i_c}\cap  F_{j_c})=\int_{ E_{i_c}\cap  F_{j_c}} f ~~d\mu=\int_{ E_{i_c}\cap  F_{j_c}} g~~ d\mu=b_{j_c}\cdot \mu ( E_{i_c}\cap  F_{j_c})$$
$$ \Rightarrow \left(a_{i_c}-b_{j_c}\right)\cdot \mu ( E_{i_c}\cap  F_{j_c})=0$$
$$\Rightarrow \mu ( E_{i_c}\cap  F_{j_c})=0$$
$$\Rightarrow \mu (K)=0$$

Hence $f=g ~\mu ~$ -almost everywhere.

> (1) Is my above proof correct ?
>
> (2) If it is then where we use $ \int_X f ~~d\mu=\int_X g ~~d\mu <\infty $?

Comment: The simple function part is just complicating things. Let $E_n = \{ x | f(x) > g(x) + {1 \over n}\}$, then $\mu E_n = 0$. Since this is true for all $n$ we have $\mu \{ x | f(x) > g(x) \} = 0$. Repeating with $f,g$ swapped finishes.